# Dojo widget declaration string - is it a temporary thing?

Tags: inheritance, widget, dojo, amd

I'm wondering if this is a temporary thing ('my.example.Widget') now that AMD is on the scene, or is it there to be?

```
declare('my.example.Widget', [], {

});
```

If I have a widget defined like above, how can I check the type of a widget? Is there a way to do this that works with AMD?

Comment: sorry, but i dont get the question. can you explain in other words ?

Comment: You shouldn't need it anymore, though it is good practice for backwards compatibility. You're saying if you declare your widget like `declare([], {})` your code cannot recognize your widget type? Have you tried at least having your widget extend _dijit/_WidgetBase_? Also, if you are going to include the String, the newer style in v1.7+ is "my/example/Widget". If you don't do it like that and try to use it declaratively with `data-dojo-type="my.example.Widget"` you will get an error. Now that I think about it, how are you trying to use this widget so that you get the unreconized TypeError?

Comment: Since I'm using Dojo's .isInstanceOf() function, I cannot imagine how would this work with / and not ., passing in a type and not a string?

Comment: You say "can you try at least..." Now I'm wondering - what is the ultimate way to check for widget type in Dojo/AMD? Keep in mind, I wan't to know everything, even if it's an instance of a mixin, not just the main type.

Comment: Have tried it with widget.isInstanceOf('my/example/Widget') and it fails.

Comment: Ah, I see, that is because `instanceOf` is supposed to be used with an actual Widget class function. I'll demonstrate in an answer.

Comment: Dojo does not provide a way to get the entire inheritance chain of a Widget out of the box, but I can think of a few implementations of a function that will get you that (if that is what you are looking for also).

Answer (score 1):

The way to check if your Dijit widget inherits from a specific Widget or Mixin is to use the `isInstanceOf` function as follows:

```
var Widget = declare([_WidgetBase], {
     name: "Widget_Name",
     id: "some_id"
});
var widgetInstance = new Widget();
console.log(widgetInstance.isInstanceOf(Widget)); // True
console.log(widgetInstance.isInstanceOf(_WidgetBase)); // True
console.log(widgetInstance.isInstanceOf(_TemplatedMixin)); // False
```

You can see it in action with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfUmu/).

Comment: So you have to check it in the context where the type you're checking against is imported as a dependency?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I can think of a custom function that you could use to pass a String in instead, but it would require some "dirty" introspection of "hidden" widget properties. By dirty, I mean that it is a poor practice according to dojo, because you have to access your widget class' Meta-Information. Dojo has this to say about such a thing: _All meta-information is a subject to change and should not be used in the course of normal coding. If you use it, be ready to update your code, when it changes._

Comment: If that is okay with you (the fact that it is subject to break without much warning because of Dojo library "back-end" changes), then ask another StackOverflow question regarding how such a thing can be done (check if widget is certain type based on string) and I will be happy to give you some options.